# Deleting node from BST without using generics

Tags: binary-search-tree

I can't seem to find the correct logic to delete node from binary search tree.

```
public void delete(int key){
    node current=root;
    int flag=0;
    if(current.data==key){
        System.out.println(key+" is deleted");
        current.rightchild=null;
        current.leftchild=null;
        current=null;
    }
    else{
        while(true){
        if(current.data>key){
            current=current.leftchild;
            if(current==null){
                flag=1;
                break;        
            }
            if(current.data==key){
                System.out.println(key+" is deleted");
                current.leftchild=null;
                current.rightchild=null;
                current=null;

                break;
            }
         }
        else{
           current=current.rightchild;
           if(current==null){
               flag=1;
               break;
           }
           if(current.data==key){
               System.out.println(key+" is deleted");
               current.leftchild=null;
               current.rightchild=null;
               current=null;
               break;
           }
        }
      }
    }
    if(flag==1){`enter code here`
        System.out.println(key+" Not Found");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I use these functions to delete a node in a BST, try it...note that my functions are templated to 3 elements, 1 for ID and 2 for Data.....

```
    template <class T, class U,class V> class Node
{
public:
    T ID;
    U data1;
    V data2;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    Node() { left = right = NULL; }
    Node(T ID, U data1, V data2)
    {
        this->ID = ID;
        this->data1 = data1;
        this->data2 = data2;
        left = right = NULL;
    }
    V getActors()
    {
        return data2;
    }
    ~Node()
    {
        delete left;
        delete right;
    }
};

   void Delete(T ID)
            {
                root = delete_helper(root, ID);
            }
    Node<T, U,V>* delete_helper(Node<T, U,V>* N, T ID)
    {
                if (ID < N->ID)
                {
                    N->left = delete_helper(N->left, ID);
                    return N;
                }
                else if (ID > N->ID)
                {
                    N->right = delete_helper(N->right, ID);
                    return N;
                }

                return Separate(N, ID);
            }



        Node<T, U,V>* Separate(Node<T, U,V>* N, T ID)
            {
                Node<T, U,V>*  NewNode = NULL;

                if ((N->left == NULL) && (N->right == NULL))
                {
                    delete N;
                }
                else if (N->right == NULL)
                {
                    NewNode = N->left;
                    delete N;
                }
                else if (N->left == NULL)
                {
                    NewNode = N->right;
                    delete N;
                }
                else
                {
                    NewNode = N;
                    Node<T, U,V>* R = getRightOf(N->left);
                    Node<T, U,V>* parent = Parent(R->ID);

                    N->ID = R->ID;

                    if (parent != N) {
                        parent->right = R->left;
                    }
                    else {
                        N->left = R->left;
                    }
                    delete R;
                }
                return NewNode;
            }
```

Comment: This is for your request for the "logic" to delete....its in c++....just to be clear

Comment: Is it possible without using generics?